# Huge PNG images in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, image

I have a lot of png images in my app which is causing my app to overload the real memory usage of my iPad2 device. My whole app folder with lots of sound files and png images is only about 50-60 MB precompiled, 90 MB on device,  but still I'm easily going up to 300MB++ at run time.. ViewControllers on top of former ViewControllers etc.. which I'm also trying to fix..

What I find strange is that by just displaying one background .png image I'm adding 12 MB onto  real memory usage(seen in instrument). The image that I used to fill a ImageView image in the storyboard is only 700 KB in my project folder. Taking it out or leaving the image field empty saves me 12 MB of memory...

I'm using a lot of these background images as well as other foreground images in the app which is eating up way to much space.

Any suggestions or help is appreciated
Thanks.

Comment: Make sure to draw where you can - huge images can kill you. Quartzcore is a useful tool for saving memory!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, 700kb image on disk space doesn't mean 700kb image in memory. It is compressed while stored on disk, but when it is taken into memory - it will grow in size.

If you are using a lot of images in your project, I would recommend using `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]` method. It doesn't cache images internally and you have more control over the memory than using `[UIImage imageNamed:]`.

For me, the general rule of thumb is this. If the image is huge and used once in the app -> `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]`, but if the image is reused in many places over the app -> `[UIImage imageNamed:]`.

In addition, if you have to use .png format because it has transparency, then you might try giving .webp a chance. This format is not supported officially in ios, however there is a custom implementation on [github](https://github.com/carsonmcdonald/WebP-iOS-example) you can take a loot at.

UPDATE:

I personally don't use interface builder in my apps at all, as I find it extremely time consuming and slow. Instead I create all views programmatically, that gives me more flexibility like choosing between `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]` or `[UIImage imageNamed:]`. You can just set an Outlet to your UIImageView and then set the actual image in code. 
As for pngs, there is no such thing as the preferred type of images in iOS. It really depends on your case. If you need transparency -> png, need just a plane image -> jpg. This is just a simple example.
And as for .webp, this format, as I have already mentioned, is not officially supported in iOS, but you can add your own support for it. Basically, .webp will let you replace .png and reduce the size of project folder without loosing transparency in your images.

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: Well yeah, that helped! but still invoked some more questions..:). Really, is this growth normal, from 0,7 -> 12..? So are you suggesting I skip using the storyboard to setup all my ImageViews and code them instead with [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]. Most of my images I use only once..aaand finally, isn't png the preferred type for iOS programming? Should I be using something else for non transparent images and consider using .webp for the transparent ones?

Comment: I guess I'm very new and found it quite easy to fiddle around in the interface builder. Especially since I was creating a storybook, thought the StoryBoard would make things easy... Now I'm seeing this huuuge memory consumption from just having ViewControllers with modal segues to other ViewControllers displaying .png images, animations and playing sounds, and it's turning into a memory nightmare (warnings/crash etc.). It's a huge process to turn it all into only code but I'm up for it if it will solve my problem!, I'm just afraid of getting the same results.

Comment: "gives me more flexibility like choosing between `imageWithContentsOfFile` or `imageNamed`. You can just set an Outlet to your UIImageView then set the image in code" ... didn't you just prove that your claim of "more flexibility" is false?  If you have a UIImageView that you created in interface builder you can choose between the two just fine.

Comment: I was giving an example of combining Interface Builder and programmatic view creation and setup. Of course you can do exactly the same thing by just setting the outlets in Interface Builder, but for me personally, this approach of creating outlets is not convenient and often causes errors during development. For instance, removing outlet in code and forgetting to remove it in the interface builder.